# previous, next button arrows

Tags: html, css

I have successfully implemented a slide show here is my code

**HTML**

```
 <div id="slider">
 <figure>
<img src="images/slides/1.jpg" alt>
<img src="images/slides/1.jpg" alt>
<img src="images/slides/1.jpg" alt>
<img src="images/slides/1.jpg" alt>
<img src="images/slides/1.jpg" alt>
<img src="images/slides/1.jpg" alt>
 </figure>
 <div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}


div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Live Demo:
https://codepen.io/RamBM/pen/PEJXqg

Now here is my question is how to implement the next button arrow and previous button arrow in the slide show.

Comment: can you share live demo here using `<>` ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/RamBM/pen/PEJXqg see the live demo

Comment: To change the a running CSS animation with a button, see https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/